# Android: onCreateView() runs from one tabs away

Tags: android, tabs, oncreate, ondestroy

I am creating a tabbed app and I am running into a problem.  onCreateView() runs when I click the tab next to where I am.  What I mean is if I have three tabs  (setup, maps, and motor) the onCreateView() view for maps and setup will run if I click on the motor tab.  Also the onDestroyView() for motor will not run until I get two tabs away by clicking on setup. Is there anyway around this, and have them run when the specific tab is clicked or moved away from?

Comment: Can you add some code which will give better idea on what is wrong

Comment: Are you using `ViewPager`? I thought this was expected behaviour - as a minimum, the tabs immediately to the left and right of the active one are created so they are ready if swiped to.

Comment: I am using ViewPager. do you know if there is any way around it though?  jumping from the first to last tab seems to take just as long as from the ones next to each other, so I don't think pre-loading is really necessary.

Comment: @JohnF No, the minimum you can set it to is one. I would argue that this is what you would want to happen as well, otherwise you would be inflating fragments every time you switched tabs, which can cause lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because you are using a `ViewPager` to display your tabbed content.

The `ViewPager` is designed to preload content in (a minimum of one of) the tabs/fragments on either side of the current tab/fragment. This is the case because Android needs to preload this content in order to display it responsively when you change/swipe between tabs/fragments in your `ViewPager`.

This cannot be disabled, as the minimum number of adjacent tabs you can set to be pre-loaded is 1 (meaning that the content in the tabs to the immediate left and right will always be pre-loaded when using a `ViewPager`).

I suggest figuring out why this is a problem for your app (as in most cases it shouldn't be), and then deciding whether or not a `ViewPager` is appropriate for your particular application.. as the behavior you are describing is expected for a `ViewPager`.